# Php variable from php file to php file using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a small problem. I need to send a php variable from php file to second php file using setInterval. I dont know how i can write php variable in jquery code.

first.php

```
<?php

$phpvariable=1;
?>
```

In JavaScript

```
setInterval(function odswiez(id)
{

$('#chat').load('second.php?id=<here php variable how?>');
}, 3000);
});
```

second.php

```
<?php
$w=$_GET['id'];
echo $w;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to echo your value

```
$('#chat').load('second.php?id=<?php echo $variable ?>');
}, 3000);
```

Alternative to do this will be..

```
$('#chat').load('second.php?id=<?php echo "id-{$variable}" ?>');
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

insted of

```
setInterval(function odswiez(id)
{

$('#chat').load('second.php?id=<here php variable how?>');
}, 3000);
```

to

```
setInterval(function odswiez(id)
{

    $.ajax({
        url: "second.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: { id: "<?php echo $php_id; ?>" }
        success: function(data){
            $('#chat').load(data);
        },
        error: function(){}             
    });


}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's isn't the best way to manage this kind of Ajax calls,
First, I suggest you instead of bringing an entire PHP file passing a GET argument, you should just pass the params and receive just plain data.

```js
var myvalue = $('.whateverinput').val();

$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json", //can be post or get
      url: "second.php", //you php who will recive data
      data: {myname : myvalue},
      success: function(data) {
        // Callback if all things goes Ok you will recive data 
        $(".the-return").html("here we atach the response"+data);
      },
      error: function(xhr, error){
        //if something wrong callback do something
        console.debug(xhr); console.debug(error);
      }
    });
```

I recommend using JSON to send/receive your data between PHP and javascript.
You can find more info in :

[Example using ajax php and using json](http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/)

Good Luck!